# Using the android generated build.xml, disable a dependent project from ANT clean and build steps

Tags: android, ant, android-xml

I have added a Third Party project, to an Android project, that needed some massaging to compile into our code, and have it checked into our CVS / Build process.

I don't want it to build, as I am happy with the library as it is, and want don't want ant cleaning it (deleting the jar) or trying to rebuild it.

I do want other projects to build through ant, so I don't want a blanket 'dont.do.deps' (which doesn't appear to disable the clean step either, though I haven't tested this too fully yet).

If it is relevant, or useful, I am using SVN and Team City as Source Control and Integration Builder.

Is this possible?